# Select the most recent row where 2 columns contain the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table of street codes and county codes. I need to only select the most recent row (ordered by created date) of any rows where these 2 columns are the same.

Ex.

[image]

Here only the last row should be selected, since it has the newest created date, where the Kommunekode and Vejkode are the same.

How can I filter my select statement to allow this logic? I tried using the distinct keyword, but that does not take the Created date into account.

My current code for the view:

```
SELECT
    Infohub_RowId,
    Infohub_CreatedDate,
    Id,
    Sekvensnummer,
    Tidspunkt,
    Operation,
    Kommunekode,
    Vejkode,
    Oprettet,
    Aendret,
    Navn,
    Vejnavn,
    Navngivenvej_id,
    Aendret AS Infohub_ValidityDate
FROM (
    SELECT
        Infohub_RowId,
        Infohub_CreatedDate,
        Sekvensnummer,
        Tidspunkt,
        Operation,
        Id,
        Kommunekode,
        Vejkode,
        Oprettet,
        Aendret,
        Navn,
        Vejnavn,
        Navngivenvej_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Aendret DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM 
        Dawa.tDelta_Vejstykke) AS x
WHERE x.RowNum = 1
```

The view should "clean up" the data, by selecting the newest duplicate records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Infohub_CreatedDate` in order by and `Kommunekode,Vejkode` these two column in partition by

```
 SELECT
        Infohub_RowId,
        Infohub_CreatedDate,
        Id,
        Sekvensnummer,
        Tidspunkt,
        Operation,
        Kommunekode,
        Vejkode,
        Oprettet,
        Aendret,
        Navn,
        Vejnavn,
        Navngivenvej_id,
        Aendret AS Infohub_ValidityDate
    FROM (
        SELECT
            Infohub_RowId,
            Infohub_CreatedDate,
            Sekvensnummer,
            Tidspunkt,
            Operation,
            Id,
            Kommunekode,
            Vejkode,
            Oprettet,
            Aendret,
            Navn,
            Vejnavn,
            Navngivenvej_id,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Kommunekode,
Vejkode ORDER BY Infohub_CreatedDate DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM 
            Dawa.tDelta_Vejstykke) AS x
    WHERE x.RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't see any duplicates in the data now.

Answer (score 1):

You want `row_number()` but `Kommunekode, Vejkode` should be in `partition` clause :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Kommunekode, Vejkode ORDER BY Infohub_CreatedDate DESC) AS Seq
      FROM Dawa.tDelta_Vejstykke t
     ) t
WHERE Seq = 1;
```